# Why there is so little western coverage of Japan Emperor's conciliatory tone in his 2015 New Year speech?

Tags: armed-conflict, japan

According to [Japan Times](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2015/01/01/national/emperor-asks-nation-learn-history-new-year-statement/#.VKcvwF1VKlM), Emperor Akihito issued a call to learn from history:

> “I think it is most important for us to take this opportunity to study and learn from the history of this war, starting with the Manchurian Incident of 1931, as we consider the future direction of our country,” the 81-year-old emperor said in the statement released via the Imperial Household Agency.

I googled around for about 30 minutes, there is very little mention of this content in major western media.

I have reason to suspect that, when the whole truth comes out, Japanese behavior in Manchuria was not as bad as we were told, and the communist rule was actually much worse.

Comment: Why do you suspect that? To me this statement by Akihito Tenno sounds more like a warning to not let history repeat itself.

Comment: @Philipp -  “No nation was ever so virtuous as each believes itself, and none was ever so wicked as each believes the other.” --Bertrand Russell

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. This could be anything from most people didn't read it as conciliatory to the western media don't think anybody will care.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this statement doesn't find a lot of feedback in the international media is because the [Emperor of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_of_Japan) has, like most constitutional monarchs, de-facto no political power. Whatever he says is in no way binding for Japanese politics and even less relevant for other countries.

For that reason, statements by constitutional monarchs rarely get international media attention outside of the tabloid press.

For comparison: How much did you hear in the international press from the new year speeches of the constitutional monarchs of Denmark, Netherlands, England, Belgium, Norway, Spain or Sweden?

Comment: Or Germany's figurehead (With close to no political power)? Nothing, even when he called for Germany to participate in wars again - http://www.bundespraesident.de/SharedDocs/Reden/EN/JoachimGauck/Reden/2014/140131-Munich-Security-Conference.html (at a conference of the arms industry).